# How to scale at the centre bottom

Tags: transforms

I am having a difficulty in blender with scaling. I have this shape that I want to scale at the bottom, however, upon scaling, it always scale towards the active vertice. What I want is to scale the bottom shape towards the bottom centre. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Provide some images or attach your here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/